# Convert server timestamp to date excel

Tags: excel, timestamp

I have following server time stamp.

```
1448600000000
```

Can somebody help me in converting it to date?

I used the given 2 formulas but it didn't work.

```
=DATE(1970,1,1)+B2/60/60/24
```

and

```
=(((B2/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1)
```

Comment: The dates that I am getting are all 1970, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are trying to get the date and time which is similar to JavaScript. The timestamp that you refer is in millisecond. You can use the below formula and set the format of the target cell to custom and 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss' (You must set this)

```
=DATE(1970,1,1)+INT(B2/1000/60/60/24)+TIME(INT((B2-(INT(B2/1000/60/60/24)*24*60*60*1000))/1000/60/60),INT(MOD(((B2-(INT(B2/1000/60/60/24)*24*60*60*1000))/1000/60),60)),MOD(((B2-(INT(B2/1000/60/60/24)*24*60*60*1000))/1000),60))
```

if you want only the date part. Then format the cell into date and use the below formula

```
=DATE(1970,1,1)+INT(B2/1000/60/60/24)
```

in both the case you need to ensure that the cell format is (must) set to date or date time format.

Comment: The first formula worked. Thanks a lot.(Although really a long one, I'll try to remember that) :-)

Comment: A bit of simplified formula
=DATE(1970,1,1)+INT(B2/1000/60/60/24)+TIME(INT((B2-(INT(B2/86400000)*86400000))/3600000),INT(MOD(((B2-(INT(B2/3600000)*3600000))/60000),60)),MOD(B2/1000,60))